# Transfer XLM from old stellar wallet 10/10/21

Tags: stellar-core

Stellar Explorer shows my XLM , Coins with GDU... Address.  My Old Wallet, Stargazer depicts SAUG...as Private Key under "Export Account".  What Next ?? I am trying to put coins on Exodus. There were no seed phrases when it was originally setup. Thank you any help appreciated.